# Excel VBA macro executes line and then crashes with no error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write an excel macro that is linked to the sheet.selectionchange event handler. Basically whenever they select a new cell, I want it to look for comments within a range of cells and set the value of the cell equal to the comment text.

The problem I am having is that no matter what method I use to loop through the range of cells, it will work properly for the very first cell in the range, and after that line executes it just stops running for no apparent reason. I've tried stepping through it and it never reaches the next line. Here is my code. I've tried 2 types of loops and left one of them commented out as an example.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("K4:L137")
    If Not cell.Comment Is Nothing Then
        cell.Value = cell.Comment.Text
    End If
Next cell

'Row = 4
'Column = 11
'Do While Column < 13
    'Do While Row < 138
        'If Not Cells(Row, Column).Comment Is Nothing Then
            'Cells(Row, Column).Value = Cells(Row, Column).Comment.Text
        'End If
        'Row = Row + 1
    'Loop
    'Row = 4
    'Column = Column + 1
'Loop

End Sub
```

Just trying to figure out why it doesn't continue beyond a single iteration? The last line to execute is

```
cell.Value = cell.Comment.Text
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `CommentThreaded` property exists in your version of Excel?

Comment: @RobertBaron My version does not support `CommentThreaded`, but the `ElseIf` condition containing that property is a recent addition and it was showing the same results even without it

Comment: My version does not support that property either and it throws an error when it tries to evaluate it. I guess you will have to rely on catching the error to support versions where the property is not there.

Comment: @RobertBaron I tested it and it throws an error if reaches that line, so I'll update my original post to show the previous version that wasn't working either

Comment: Hmm, your update version works without  error in my version of Excel.

Comment: on more than one cell? Because it only works on the first occurrence of a comment for me

Comment: Yes, I tested with two consecutive cells that have comments.

Comment: Please try `For Each Cell In Range(...).Cells`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be some sort of bug with older versions of excel. The same code with the latest version seems to work properly.

Comment: You may want to wrap the code with Application.EnableEvents = False/True. Potentially the issue is when the first cell places the comment text, it may trigger the call again. I can't test this though; my version works fine.